# How to make an api call whenever the screen is focused

Tags: reactjs

I want to make an api call whenever that screen is focused, in mobile application I have an idea that we can use useFocuseffect () but in web how can I implement this please let me know in web how can I make an api call whenever that screen is focused

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `useEffect()` hook
Or the `useLayoutEffect()` hook depending on how fast you want your api calls to be made.

`useEffect()` is triggered after DOM Manipulations are painted

`useLayoutEffect()` is triggered synchronously before DOM Manipulations are painted

Answer (score 0):

You can listen to the `focus` event on the `window` object for this:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  // The function that will make the wanted API call
  function makeApiCall() {
     // Your code here
  }
  
  // Add an event listener on the window object for the focus event
  // This will call the makeApiCall function whenever the window gets focus
  window.addEventListener('focus', makeApiCall)

  // In the cleanup function, we need to remove the event listener added 
  // previously
  return () => { 
    window.removeEventListener('focus', makeApiCall)
  }
}, [])
```